# Proper way to use "Rule of Transposition" in a proof?

Tags: logic

I'm viewing the proofs for the Comparison Test of limits of series.

E.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Comparison_Test#Proof

This is the proof for :

Given $0 ≤ a_n ≤ b_n$

> $b_n$ converges => $a_n$ converges (1)

Which can be "transposed" to prove

> $a_n$ diverges => $b_n$ diverges (2)

But what's the proper way to formulate the argument for the divergence?
 Assuming the proof is proven for convergent series already.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You are asking what is the "proper" way to formulate the argument. What here is "improper"?

Comment: @5xum I mean what is the antithesis? Or what assumptions one can take from the convergent case in order to prove the divergent case? Esp. when the direction of logic is "=>" and not "<=>".

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the original theorem is:

> For any pair of sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\forall n: 0\leq a_n \leq b_n$, we know that if the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ converges, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges.

This theorem says, therefore, for all elements of some set, some implication is true. Now you probably know that $p\implies q$ is equivalent to $\neg q \implies \neg p$. Therefore, the original theorem is equivalent to

> For any pair of sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\forall n: 0\leq a_n \leq b_n$, we know that if the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ does not converge, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ does not converge.

Pair that with the definition of divergence (somehing diverges if and only if it does not converge).